# Python thread still alive after 'main' thread terminate？

Tags: python, multithreading

In **python 3.8** and Ubuntu 20.04, this code starts a thread at 'main' thread, and do nothing after that. I think this process maybe exit for main thread exited, but the process still running until `Ctrl+C`.

```
import threading

def do_something():
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target = do_something)
    thread.start()
```

What's more, I add a `sys.exit()` after `thread.start()`, the process prints "After thead start" as expected, but still running. This is amazing.

```
import threading
import sys

def do_something():
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target = do_something)
    thread.start()
    print("After thead start")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: While not stated as clearly as I'd like, the official docs do say that the program won't terminate if any non-daemon threads are still running: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon *"The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left."*

Comment: You can make it a daemon by adding: `thread = threading.Thread(target = do_something, daemon = True)`

Comment: So, is there any way to exit when some non-daemon still alive?

Comment: The way is to make it a daemon